# Contributing to open-source project while maintaining a copy locally in git

Tags: git, github

Our company is contributing to open-source projects (called upstream) but at the same time we have our own in-house fork (called origin). Whenever there's a release in upstream, we fork the release branch, then we add our feature onto our internal fork. After we pass the internal review, we contribute it back to upstream. This means we will have our internal changes, and upstream will also have their own changes (if they don't include in release yet).

Currently we cherry-pick commits, but there will be times where branches divert quickly and it becomes difficult to maintain multiple branches and commits.

One scenario is this:

If upstream cuts a release at commit C, and their main keeps on going, we will only take upto commit C

```
upstream:
A -- B -- C (release 1) -- D -- E
```

If we want to develop a new feature, we will develop it based on latest commit from upstream, which is E (because ultimately we want to contribute everything back to main)

So upstream becomes:

```
upstream:
A -- B -- C (release 1) -- D -- E -- F'
```

However, our origin still sits at commit C. It will look like

```
origin:
A -- B -- C -- F'
```

This will make the git history hard to maintain because now the history divert.

I'm wondering what others' strategies are to maintain this kind of situation?

Comment: Rebase or merge.

Comment: I would say merge rather than rebase. Always merge both `upstream` and any feature branches into your internal version. If you want to contribute a feature to `upstream` you would have to base the feature-branch on `upstream` rather than your internal fork.

Answer (score 0):

You should have at least 3 branches:

1. Your main branch
2. The upstream main branch
3. One or more development branches.

You will never merge into the upstream branch, except to pull from the remote to keep it up-to-date. Otherwise, you will treat it like a local development branch, merging it *into* another branch for testing purposes.

When you want to submit a patch, submit a pull request for the appropriate feature branch (which has already been merged into *your* main). Once the pull request has been accepted, there should be no trouble merging the new upstream into your main, because those changes are already present.

Comment: This is what my current strategy is. The problem with this approach is we never merge from upstream main tho, since main can be unstable. We always wait for release and then rebase w/e we have on top of the release. 

Now we are just taking our patches and applying to releases